# Pdfsharp And MigradDoc : How to make the right white panel responsive utilizing migradoc and pdfsharp?

Tags: .net, pdfsharp, migradoc

```
//-- migradoc----------
    <code>
          Document document = new Document();
          Section section = document.AddSection();
          Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
    </code>
```

//---pdfSharp ---------------------------

```
    <code>
        PdfDocument layoutDoc = new PdfDocument();
        PdfPage page = layoutDoc.AddPage();
        XGraphics gfx = CreatePageLayout(page);
        XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 12);
    </code>
```

//--- Render migradoc objects---------------------------------------------
//--- Here document is the migradoc document containing all the data which will be used in the pdfsharp's document
        
         `MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer docRenderer = new DocumentRenderer(document);
                    docRenderer.PrepareDocument();
                    //---Length Tags
                    int leftPanelYaxis = 0;
                    int RightPanelHeight = 0;
                    try
                    {
                        // Render the paragraph.You can render tables or shapes the same way.
                        docRenderer.RenderObject(gfx, XUnit.FromCentimeter(0.7), XUnit.FromCentimeter(0.5), "6cm", name);
                        docRenderer.RenderObject(gfx, XUnit.FromCentimeter(0.7), XUnit.FromCentimeter(2), "6cm", about);
                        docRenderer.RenderObject(gfx, XUnit.FromCentimeter(0.3), XUnit.FromCentimeter(2), "0.6cm", aboutme_icon);
                    }`

[[image: Below is the image of the Resume. The Left side is fixed and the right needs to be responsive. Currently I will have to handle the content and give coordinates to add it on pdfSharp document. In migradoc this is handled but the left colored panel has fixed data. This cannot be achieved in migraDoc alone. So there has to be some combination of migraDoc and PdfSharp.][1]][1]
//--- How to make this right side dynamic. migradoc has got this feature to achieve this. But the Left Panel is colored and fixed while the right panel will be responsive. How can this be achieved. 
Currently the Data on Right Panel is overflowing and overlapping since it is a onepage. As I am rendering the Migradoc's objects it is overflowing on the pdfsharp document. Is there any alternative to solve this.

Comment: I feel tempted to flag this as "unclear what you're asking". The inconsistent formatting does not help to understand the issue. Make sure you set the correct page width before calling `PrepareDocument()`.

Comment: Hi, with the current implementation i am able to to add only single page but if data is increased then i have to give a page break also if the data size is more than one page it overflows in right panel since i am "Rendering the paragraph object". This issue is not present in migradoc since it adds the additional data to next page i.e. page break is handled by it. But using migradoc alone to generate this two panels and then concatenate as one. Can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

`RenderObject` does not handle page breaks. You can use it only to render a single object to a single page. You can make the page really huge using custom page sizes.

`RenderPage` takes care of page breaks. Create a document with several objects and then use `RenderPage` to draw it.
A sample that uses `RenderPage` (for a different purpose) can be seen here:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3172

From `FormattedDocument` you can query information about the sizes and positions of objects if you need that.

Comment: Hi I tried to use render page but only the last page is getting rendered <code> /*Page counter*/ int pageCount = docRenderer.FormattedDocument.PageCount; 
 PdfPage page = pdfDocument.AddPage();
 XGraphics gfx = CreatePageLayout(page);
                XRect rect = GetRect(idx);
                XGraphicsContainer container = gfx.BeginContainer(rect, A4Rect, XGraphicsUnit.Point);// Render the page. docRenderer.RenderPage(gfx, idx + 1);
// Pop the previous graphical state  gfx.EndContainer(container);</code>

Comment: I saw this example in which they have used  two pdf Documents. [link](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/CombineDocuments-sample.ashx). But In my case I am generating the pdf files at run time. One PdfDocument and the other MirgraDoc document. Then can I use this technique as shown in the link to combine both the documents and get the Desired Layout ?

Comment: Re 1st comment: no loop in your code, so only one call to `RenderPage()` and only one page gets drawn. Re 2nd comment: There are always options to make things more complicated. You can create one document with PDFsharp and save to a stream, create another document with MigraDoc and save to a stream - and then use the linked sample to read both streams and combine them. But I think saving to streams is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
     /// <summary>
            /// Merge Left and Right Panels
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="rightPanelMigraDoc"></param>
            /// <param name="leftPanelPdfDoc"></param>
            /// <param name="gfx"></param>
    <code>
            public static void MergePanels(Document migraDocument, PdfDocument leftPanelPdfDoc, XGraphics gfx)
            {
                PdfPage page = null;

                //concatenation of Left and Right Panels 
                // Create a renderer and prepare (layout) the Migradoc document
                MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer docRenderer = new DocumentRenderer(migraDocument);
                docRenderer.PrepareDocument();

                //get pagecount of the rightpanelMigraDoc
                int rightPageCount = docRenderer.FormattedDocument.PageCount;
                int leftPageCount = leftPanelPdfDoc.PageCount;
                // Loop to add leftPanel pages equal to rightPanel and Merge by rendering
                int index = 0;
                do
                {
                    //for single left panel page only.
                    if (index == 0)
                    {
                        docRenderer.RenderPage(gfx, index + 1);
                        index++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        page = leftPanelPdfDoc.AddPage();
                        page.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.A4;
                        gfx = CreatePageLayout(page);
                        // Render the page. Note that page numbers start with 1.
                        docRenderer.RenderPage(gfx, index + 1);
                        index++;
                    }
                }
                while (index < rightPageCount);
            }
    </code>
```

But This One Above Works For Single Left Page And Responsive Right Panel (Pages are added in the pdfsharp Document and then using that gfx the MigraDoc page is rendered on it).
However this can be improved to make the left panel also to have multiple pages first and then get the gfx (XGraphics Object) of Each page and render the Right Panel MigraDoc